# Set custom window property in xaml

Tags: wpf, window, dependency-properties

I have the following code:

```
public partial class NewWindow: Window
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PropNameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
                    "PropName",
                    typeof(int),
                    typeof(NewWindow),
                    null);

    public int PropName
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)GetValue(PropNameDependencyProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(PropNameDependencyProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

Now when I try to use my new property I can't compile:

```
<Window x:Class="AppName.NewWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:my="clr-namespace:AppName"
    Title="NewWindow" Height="300" Width="300"
    PropName="5"                          <-"property does not exist" error here
    >
```

I'm probably just misunderstanding something, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: Does error appear even after Rebuild Solution? it could warn whilst edid before the first build

Comment: @sll Yes, it's still there after a Rebuild Solution

Comment: Try out `NewWindow.PropName` instead of `PropName`

Comment: Not sure if you need the namespace.... try `my:NewWindow.PropName` too

Comment: I tried NewWindow.PropName and my:NewWindow.PropName.  I think @Matthew Walton figured out my problem.

Comment: I've been frustrated about the same issue for a long time. The only other solution I can think of is setting the property via a style setter but that is hardly elegant either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand it, the reason it can't find the property is because it's looking for it in the Window class, not in your NewWindow class. Why? Because the XAML tag name is Window, not NewWindow.

I tried changing the tag to NewWindow, but you can't actually do that, because your XAML and the code behind are cooperating to define the NewWindow class and you can't define a class in terms of itself. This is why the toplevel XAML element is always the parent class, and this suggests a solution: define the property in a new class which inherits from Window (call it, for the sake of argument, ParentWindow), and then derive NewWindow from that, so you get something like

```
<local:ParentWindow x:Class="TestApp.NewWindow"
    PropName="5"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    ...
</local:ParentWindow>
```

I appreciate this is not necessarily a very elegant solution.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If you declare a dependecy property in the code behind you have to access to it through some binding syntax

Comment: @Mackho assuming this question is directed at me, the reason I want this is to set a value range for a validation rule by binding to the window dependency property.  If there is a more elegant way of doing that I'm happy to do it a different way.